# Could NOT find GLib2_glib (missing: GLIB2_GLIB_LIBRARY GLIB2_GLIB_INCLUDE_DIR GLIB2_GLIBCONFIG_INCLUDE_DIR)

Tags: installation, lcm

When I trying to install LCM in my Ubuntu, using commands

```
$ mkdir build
$ cd build
$ cmake ..
$ make
$ sudo make install
```

and when comes to `$cmake ..`
it returns :

```
-- Could NOT find GLib2_glib (missing: GLIB2_GLIB_LIBRARY GLIB2_GLIB_INCLUDE_DIR GLIB2_GLIBCONFIG_INCLUDE_DIR) 
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.16/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:146 (message):
  Could NOT find GLib2 (missing: GLIB2_GLIB_LIBRARY glib)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake-3.16/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:393 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  cmake/FindGLib2.cmake:114 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  CMakeLists.txt:10 (enter code herefind_package)

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/rusath/Downloads/lcm-1.4.0/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

Answer (score 0):

Already solved

the reason is lacking `libglib2.0-dev` package